# Python Pandas .str.extract method fails when indexing

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'd like to set values on a slice of a DataFrame using `.loc` using pandas str extract method `.str.extract()` however, it's not working due to indexing errors. This code works perfectly if I swap `extract` with `contains`.

Here is a sample frame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'name': [
            'JUNK-0003426', 'TEST-0003435', 'JUNK-0003432', 'TEST-0003433', 'TEST-0003436',
        ], 
        'value': [
            'Junk', 'None', 'Junk', 'None', 'None',
        ]
    }
)
```

Here is my code:

```
df.loc[df["name"].str.startswith("TEST"), "value"] = df["name"].str.extract(r"TEST-\d{3}(\d+)")
```

How can I set the `None` values to the extracted regex string

Comment: Can you do a practical example? What should be the value for name `TEST-0003435`? @Oliver

Comment: `\d{3}(\d+)` can be shortened to `\d{4,}` (translates to: "4 or more digits"), but this probably doesn't change how your code runs

Comment: @Hein see the capture group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm the problem seems to be that `.str.extract` returns a `pd.DataFrame`, you can `.squeeze` it to turn it into a series and it seems to work fine:

```
df.loc[df["name"].str.startswith("TEST"), "value"] = df["name"].str.extract(r"TEST-\d{3}(\d+)").squeeze()
```

indexing alignment takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to get the group, you can replace the rest with the empty string:

```
df.loc[df['value']=='None', 'value'] = df.loc[df['value']=='None', 'name'].str.replace('TEST-\d{3}', '')
```

Was this answer helpful to your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to do it:

```py
df.loc[df["name"].str.startswith("TEST"), "value"] = df["name"].str.extract(r"TEST-\d{3}(\d+)").loc[:,0]
```

Output:

```
           name value
0  JUNK-0003426  Junk
1  TEST-0003435  3435
2  JUNK-0003432  Junk
3  TEST-0003433  3433
4  TEST-0003436  3436
```